# Read the URL and contents of the next page after submitting the form in Python

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I have a form that has to be filled and I have written the code using `mechanize` to fill the form details and submit it. Everything is working fine as expected and I'm able to submit it and I'm also getting the confirmation as `Form Submitted Successfully`in the next page.

Now, I have to read this content, the Status- `Form Submitted Successfully` or if the attempt is not successful - `Form NOT Submitted Successfully` from the next page (page after submission of the form) along with other details like my name, form number, form name and status which all are displayed in one line.

```
DEV D   0911   Scientific_Conference     Form Submitted Successfully
```

After the code - `res = br.submit()`, how do I read all these contents of the next page and display it in my output. What should I do to capture the next page contents and display accordingly? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Kindly help me in understanding this process. Thanks in advance.

I'm not even able to display the html contents.

```
Code I used (but not working):
    res = br.submit()
    final = res.geturl()
    print final
    x = br.open(final)
    print "Loading...\n"
    print (x.read())
    print "program ended"
```

Comment: What happens when you do `print (x.read())`?

Comment: I'm able to get the complete html contents of the next page, but how do I read the details I want to get and output them ? I get all the required details I want to output between the `<TR></TR>` tags